# Click a point on Dot-plot in Shiny R

Tags: shiny-reactivity

I am working on a Shiny App design and I wonder how to click a point on a dot-plot in Shiny R. I want to design an app that if the users select a point on the dot-plot, they can see the correspond table (3 columns ). The plot is a p-value distribution. The following is my code:

```
ui:
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(pander)
fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
      titlePanel(h3("Chi-Squared Goodness-fit-Test and Simulation ")),
      fluidRow(
        column(3, offset = 0.5,wellPanel(
          sliderInput("n", "Number of Samples:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 50 ,
                      step = 1),
          sliderInput("n2", "The number of Categories:", min = 1, max = 8, value = 5 ,
                      step = 1) ,
          sliderInput("n3", "The number of Simulation:", min = 1, max = 1000, value = 5 ,
                      step = 1),
          submitButton("Submit")
        )),
        column(7,align="center", tableOutput("values")),

        column(5,offset=1, align="center",
               plotOutput("plot1", click=" Click" ,width = 600, height = 430)
       )


      )
 )

 server:
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(pander)
function(input, output) {

output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
num_of_samples = input$n
nn= input$n2
ss= input$n3
pp=numeric(0)
 for(i in 1:ss){
  x <- sample(1:nn,num_of_samples,replace=T)

  nulls=1/(1:nn)
  total=table(x)
  expected=nulls*total
  a <- chisq.test(table(x), correct= FALSE, rescale.p=TRUE )
  pp[i]=a$p.value

}
  if (ss<=50) {stripchart(pp,method = "stack",offset = 0.8, at = .15, pch = 19,
           main="P-value Distribution of Chi-Squared Test", xlab="P Value")}

else {hist(pp,breaks=5,main="P-value Distribution of Chi-Squared Test", xlab="P Value")}

})


sliderValues <- reactive({
num_of_samples = input$n
nn= input$n2
# pp=numeric(0)
x <- sample(1:nn,num_of_samples,replace=T)

# Compose data frame
xx=cbind(paste0(LETTERS[1:nn]),table(x ),round(rep(num_of_samples/nn,nn),2)) 
xx=as.data.frame(xx)
colnames(xx)=c("Categories","Observed Value","Expected Value")
xx
 })


output$values <- renderTable({
sliderValues()},
align="c"
 )


 }
```